# datatable and highchart functionality not working with 'View All' bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, tabs

I am using bootstrap tabs to show different charts and tabular data on a screen. There are 11 tabs plus a 'View All' tab I created that would allow the user to see the content of the 11 at one time.

Each table has anchor tags that when clicked trigger a modal pop-up. CSS styling changes the mouse to a pointer. In addition, the charts are rendered via high charts and as such, have the hover over on the different sections of the graph to display the specific count or dollar amount of that particular section.

[image: active tab]

The issue arises when i select the 'View All' tab that has the following selector:

```
href="div[id^='tab_']"
```

which successfully finds and displays all the divs for each of the 11 sections nicely BUT i cannot click on anything within the datattables, the hover styling on the tables do not work, nor does any of the highchart functionality.

When I click back to an individual tab everything works as expected again.

No errors are present and I have tried across all 3 browsers to identify if the behavior might be different, and it was consistent.

The strange thing is when using f12, if I try and select something within the tab content div of tab_cb I can't and it shows the incorrect div as being selected. In the screen shot below it shows that i am in tab_ms.
[image: wrong div selection]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you recreate this on jsfiddle, so there is something I can work on?

Answer (score 0):

issue was related to css styling on the divs. A class was being used that had dynamic positioning. Once it was removed on all the content divs, everything started working again.